# derived class not able to access protected setter using PropertyDescriptorCollection.SetValue

Tags: c#, reflection, typedescriptor, propertydescriptor

I have set one of my properties in my base class to have a protected setter.
this works fine and I am able to set the property in the constructor of the derived class - however when I try to set this property using the  PropertyDescriptorCollection it will not set, however using the collection works with all other properties.

I should mention that  when I rremove the protected Access modifier all works okay...but of course now it's not protected. thanks for any input.

```
 class base_a
{

 public  string ID { get; protected set; }
 public virtual void SetProperties(string xml){}
}

class derived_a : base_a
 {
   public derived_a()
    {
    //this works fine
     ID = "abc"
    }
   public override void SetProperties(string xml)
    {
      PropertyDescriptorCollection pdc = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this);
      //this does not work...no value set.
      pdc["ID"].SetValue(this, "abc");

      }
  }
```

Comment: What do you mean "does not work"? What *does* it do?

Comment: svick,no value was set when I inspected the property. There was not an exception thrown.

Comment: I assume this is because the set is protected, however I can't find anything in VS help that states this is the case. I also don't like that it does nothing with no warning or exception.

Comment: @JoelRondeau, there is no way how could this code produce a warning. An exception would make some sense.

Comment: @svick - I realize in this case, with reflection, there's no chance of a warning. Just that if you could do the same thing without reflection, you would get a compiler error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TypeDescriptor` does not know that you call it from a type that should have access to that property setter, so the `PropertyDescriptor` you're using is read-only (you can verify this by checking [its `IsReadOnly` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.propertydescriptor.isreadonly.aspx)). And when you try to set value of a read-only `PropertyDescriptor`, nothing happens.

To work around that, use normal reflection:

```
var property = typeof(base_a).GetProperty("ID");

property.SetValue(this, "abc", null);
```

Comment: thanks, it worked. Some of the properties being set are from the derived class. I checked to see if GetProperty returned a null value as an indicator if the prop was from the base class...thoughts?

Comment: Yeah, `GetProperty()` should return `null` in those cases. But if you want properties from the derived class too, just use `typeof(derived_a)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
PropertyInfo[] props = TypeDescriptor
    .GetReflectionType(this)
    .GetProperties();
props[0].SetValue(this, "abc", null);
```

Or simply

```
PropertyInfo[] props = this
    .GetType()
    .GetProperties();
props[0].SetValue(this, "abc", null);
```

(You will need a `using System.Reflection;`)